# Apache2 configuration - Virtual Host IP on AWS Linux 2

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-web-services

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vhosts/main-repo-dir"
    ServerName example.io
    ErrorLog "logs/example.io-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.io-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dev@example.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vhosts/dev-repo-dir"
    ServerName dev.example.io
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.example.io-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.example.io-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, but when I replace the asterisk(s) with a url, `DocumentRoot` defaults to `/var/www/html`:

```
<VirtualHost example.io:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vhosts/main-repo-dir"
    ServerName example.io
    ErrorLog "logs/example.io-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.io-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost dev.example.io:80>
    ServerAdmin dev@example.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vhosts/dev-repo-dir"
    ServerName dev.example.io
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.example.io-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.example.io-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1   example.io
127.0.0.1   dev.example.io
```

I'm fine with using an asterisk, I'd just like to understand why I have to in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That section only defines the ips that can reach that virtual host. In this case the `<VirtualHost *:80>` means that apache is going to let all network interfaces to access that virtualhost. The behavior I think you are experiencing is that you are getting to the default document root, because none of the virtualhosts you set are open

Comment: Right. And in AWS, those names will never match due to 1:1 NAT.

Comment: I thought they would be like localized due the hosts file. Is the hosts file initiated after vhosts?